# Incorrect style sheet in use

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

My C# MVC project uses Crystal Reports. Somehow my reports have have stopped working and display a blank page. When I inspect the site I see the error

> Obj not found
>   http://localhost:44246/aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_1055/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/images/style.css

I've verified the aspnet_client but at that directory I have a folder named `4_0_30319` instead of `4_6_1055`. When I edited the link to use that folder number I was again able to browse to the css file.

Where in my config can I change this number to be `4_0_30319`? Or is it better to just rename the folder to match this number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
            <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
                <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <businessObjects>
        <crystalReports>
            <crystalReportViewer>
                <add key="UseBrowserLocale" value="true"/>
                <add key="resourceURI" value="http://localhost/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13" />
            </crystalReportViewer>
        </crystalReports>
    </businessObjects>
</configuration>
```